# I didn't get output or error just processing for long time

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
import re

base_url = 'https://www.brambleco.com/c/furniture/cabinets-sideboards'

headers = {
    'User-Agents' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}
cab_list = []
for x in range(1,5):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.brambleco.com/c/furniture/cabinets-sideboards/page/{x}')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    product = soup.find_all('div', class_='new-product-images')
    igg=[]
    
    for img in product:
        for ig in img.find_all('img',{"data-original":True}):
            igg.append(ig)
    #print(igg)
   
    for customize in product:
        for cabinet in customize.find_all('a', href = True):
            #cab = [item.strip() for item in cabinet if str(item)]

            #print(cabinet['href'])
            m = cabinet['href']
            n = m.strip()
            cab_list.append(n)
            

            for cabinet in cab_list:
                r = requests.get(cabinet, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
                name = soup.find('h1', {'id':'product-introduction-name'}).text
                #print(name)
                table = soup.find("table", {"class": "dimension imperial"})

                cab = table.find_all('tr')
                #print(cab)
                tab = []
                for result in cab:
                    try:
                        width = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'cm'}).text.strip()
                        depth = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'inch'}).text.strip()
                        tab.append((width, depth))
                    except:
                        None
                #print(tab)
                tab2 = []
                table = soup.find("table", {"class": "product-attribute-specs"})
                for ward in table:
                    try:
                        detail = ward.find('td').text.strip()
                        tab2.append(detail)
                    except:
                        None
            tab.append(tab2)
print(tab)
```

Comment: how long time? before use `r.content`, you'd better check `r.status_code` and make sure it is 200.

Comment: You have too match requests. On first iteration you get 36 products. Then parse cabinets for each product. Btw you do not empty `cab_list`. So on each iteration you have more and more data and requests.